# Recommended configuration for wolf-xmr-miner xmr.conf with R9 290

Tags: gpu-mining, mining, ubuntu, mining-setup

I'm quite new in mining and I am using a R9 290 to mine monero with wolfs miner and Ubuntu 16. This is my xmr.conf file:

```
{
"Algorithms":
[
    {
        "name": "CryptoNight",
        "devices":
        [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "corefreq": 1000,
                "memfreq": 1300,
                "fanspeed": 65,
                "powertune": 20,
                "threads": 1,
                "rawintensity": 1040,
                "worksize": 16
            }
        ],
        "pools":
        [
            {
                "url": "stratum+tcp://pool.minexmr.com:443",
                "user": "43CvTMvvjn5A5ZvfKRyNt8gkaL6SxRamnWyhx6BGy9mnGRYjPu2m2difVRDA54mqBHGUi5qsjBGWb4zRJvDvn5F6AQJGw9k",
                "pass": "x"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

With this config I'm getting about 670-680 H/s. What i think is acceptable for this card. If i change the rawintensity things go down or up. But what is the limit? **should I put more rawintensity? or should i put it down to prevent overheating the GPU or something? Should any other parameter be changed to improve my configuration?**

Please help I'm quite lost. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

With rawintensity, you're really looking for an optimum. So when changing it a little in either direction gives you less hashpower, you will know you found the right setting. I don't think it will affect heating much, especially if you're running the clocks at stock settings.

Comment: Ok thanks, it helps. Anything about the other parameters?

Comment: Not sure, maybe someone else can provide a better answer. Fyi, my AMD GPU ignored clock settings on Linux, and setting fanspeed high enough was important to control the temperature, although I had to run it as root to let it access the fan control.